# How to setup Yarn-Workspaces correctly

Tags: node.js, gulp, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

my project got the following structure

```
project-root
- common-modules
    - build-modules
        - packageA
        - packageB
    - packageC
    - packageD
- services
    - packageE -> needs packageA, packageC / devDependency on packageD
    - packageF -> needs packageB, packageC / devDependency on packageD
```

Each package and the project-root have a package.json with all the defined dependencies and devDependencies.

What is the right way to configure my project with yarn workspaces?

I don't want a single `node_modules` folder in each package, but one in the project-root.

Setting the `package.json` in the project-root up with

```
"workspaces": [
    "common-modules/build-modules/*", 
    "common-modules/packageC",
    "common-modules/packageD",
    "services/*"
]
```

did not work, because I could not even build `packageE` since the gulp-script could not require a devDependency.

Comment: I'm not sure how gulp works.  But since you are using yarn workspaces then adding dependencies for packageE would be the command `yarn workspace packageE add packageA@^1.0` and `yarn workspace packageE add packageC@^1.0`.  Just replace the example version numbers with the correct ones.