# Yarn workspace isolation

Tags: angular, angular-library, yarn-workspaces

I'm having some problems with yarn, on empty setups (when I do not have any versions of my libs on npm).

I've a multi-module project as structured bellow:

```
root                        # Yarn workspace
 * packages
 |  * lib1-ws               # Angular workspace
 |  |  * projects
 |  |  |  * lib1
 |  |  |     * package.json
 |  |  * package.json
 |  |
 |  * lib2-ws               # Angular workspace
 |  |  * projects
 |  |  |  * lib2
 |  |  |     * package.json # peer depends on lib1
 |  |  * package.json       # depends on lib1
 |  |
 |  * lib3-ws               # Angular workspace
 |     * projects
 |     |  * lib3
 |     |     * package.json # peer depends on lib1
 |     * package.json       # depends on lib1
 |
 * package.json
```

The projects lib2-ws and lib3-ws require lib1 to be build.

I was trying to release (install, build and publish) lib1 so that I can release *lib2* and *lib3*.

But when I run `yarn workspace lib1-ws install` or `yarn install` (inside *lib1-ws* folder), yarn do try to install **lib2-ws** and **lib3-ws** as well, breaking the install operation with this error:

> error Couldn't find package "lib1@^0.0.1" required by "lib2-ws@0.0.1" on the "npm" registry.

Not sure what I'm missing, is there some command that I can run to ignore this `workspace-aggregator` thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I did not searched enough, after post this question, I read another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52613249/1703546) that give-me an idea.

My workspaces object became like this:

```
"workspaces": {
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "packages/**/projects/*"
  ]
}
```

And it works, now I can install without even build or publish.

[UPDATE]

Because some angular build particularities, after install all dependencies, the empty setup must execute some order (because yarn workspace create symlinks for the libs):

1. `build lib1 then publish lib1`
2. `yarn workspace lib2-ws add lib1@latest`
3. `yarn workspace lib3-ws add lib1@latest`
4. `build lib2 then publish lib2`
5. `build lib3 then publish lib3`

After this steps, my libs are ready on my verdaccio local repository.

Comment: hey, are you able to just install node_modules required for each workspace?

Comment: I'm not sure, because I stopped to work on that project that uses this architecture.